# Brush and Zoom d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm following this guide: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

Can you explain this line? Thanks

```
x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
```

Comment: yes, I can not find exactly what this line does. @rioV8

Comment: On github  is not explained exactly line by line

Comment: no function by function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For context, this is from some code that implements chart brushing:

```
function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}
```

We already have `x` and `x2` initialised as two time scales:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width])
```

and `s` is initialised as

```
var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
```

(where the `d3.event` is a brushing event)

The line

```
x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
```

sets the `x` scale domain by running `x2.invert` on each item in array `s` with `x2` as the `this` value. In practice, this means you are running

```
x.domain( x2.invert( s[0] ), x2.invert( s[1] ) );
```

as there are only two values in `s` and the `this` context does not affect the `invert` function. In terms of the visualisation, this is setting the time span covered by the large chart by converting the pixel values of the edges of the selection box in the bottom chart into dates on the large chart.

To briefly summarise the whole function:

```
function brushed() {
  if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom
  // get the edges of the selection box or use the maximum values (in x2.range)
  var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
  // convert those pixel values into dates, and set the x scale domain to those values
  x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));
  // redraw the top graph contents to show only the area within the x domain
  focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
  // redraw the top graph's x axis with the updated x scale domain
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
  // zoom the overlay of the top graph to reflect the new x domain
  // so that any zoom operations will scale correctly
  svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
      .scale(width / (s[1] - s[0]))
      .translate(-s[0], 0));
}
```